# $n\varphi(n)\equiv 2\pmod{\sigma(n)}$ as a primality test

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions

It is known from [Subbarao, "On two congruences for primality"](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~subbarao/documents/Subbarao1974.pdf) that $n>22$ is a prime iff $$n\sigma(n)\equiv 2\pmod{\varphi(n)},$$ where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's function and $\sigma(n)$ is sum of divisors of $n$. See also [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338203/for-which-n-is-n-sigman-equiv-2-pmod-phin)

Can we switch $\varphi(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$:

*Is $n>9$ a prime if* $$n\varphi(n)\equiv 2\pmod{\sigma(n)}?$$
(This congruence holds for $n=8$ and $9$.) I can only prove that this congruence does not hold for prime powers.

Comment: It could be true. At least I did not find any $N=p\, q$ with $p<10^5$ and $q<10^6$ where it fails. But then, it is not likely to fail and it could just be one of these $\log\log(x)$-symptomes.

Comment: well, for $n=pq$ the result immediately follows from the fact that $\sigma(n)=(1+p)(1+q)=0(\mod 4)$ and $n\phi(n)=0(\mod 4)$ unless $p$ or $q$ is $2.$

Comment: :-) I should have been thinking before randomly trying to run through examples, indeed. Thanks Alvin.

Comment: $n\varphi(n)\not\equiv0\pmod4$ only for some prime powers. It means that the most significant case is $\sigma(n)\equiv2\pmod4$.

Comment: the congrunce was studied recently in A. Dujella and F. Luca, On a variation of a congruence of Subbarao, J. Aust. Math. Soc. 93 (2012), 85-90.  http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/DL2and3.pdf

Comment: Thank you, Andrej. I think this is the best possible answer for today.

Comment: (1/3) Hi I tried to change some factors of the congruence by $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, the so-called radical of an integer. Then A) *It seems that* $\operatorname{rad}(n)\varphi(n)\equiv2\text{ mod }\sigma(n)$, *if and only if* $n$ *is prime*. With the same trick one can to get other congruences (I don't know if this "method" improve the mathematical content of the genuine problem/congruence). From the Wikipedia's article dedicated to *Table of congruences* I wrote the following congruences. B) *It seems that the only integers that satisfy* $(\operatorname{rad}(n)-1)!\equiv-1\text{ mod }n$

Comment: (2/3) *and that aren't prime numbers are* $1,25$ and $169$. C) *It seems, as a variant of Wolstenholme's theorem a congruence that seems to have the same behaviour is* $\binom{2\operatorname{rad}(n)-1}{\operatorname{rad}(n)-1}\equiv 1\text{ mod }n^3$, *for integers* $n\geq 5$. D) *It seems that the integers satisfying (a congruence similar than Wall–Sun–Sun primes, the quotient is different*) $F_{\operatorname{rad}(n)-(\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)}{5})}\equiv 0\text{ mod }n$ *are square-free.* E) *It seems that if an integer* $n>22$ *satisfies (the congruence inspired by Subbarao congruence)*

Comment: (3/3) $ n\sigma(\operatorname{rad}(n))\equiv 2\text{ mod }\varphi(n)$ *then* $n$ *is a prime number.* I hope don't disturb feel free to study these or other congruences of your invention.